# como podria pasar un objeto de una componente a otra

Tags: angular, binding

tengo una componente con diferentes modal y en cada modal debo mostrar la informacion de cada inmueble, esta informaciòn esta en otra componente. dicha informaciòn la tengo en un vector de objetos. Por lo que he leido debo usar Binding entre componentes (padre e hijo) la duda que tengo es como es un objeto el que debo pasar a la otra componente para luego mostrar sus datos, como podria hacerlo? debo declarar un objeto tipo @input inmueble y como haria para bindear todo el objeto de una componente a otra? lo que quiero es mostrar luego los valores de ese objeto en la plantilla de esa componente.

Aquì dejo una muestra de lo que tengo:

```js
tengo esta clase que viene siendo el objeto del que hablo: 

export class Inmueble {
  nombre: string="";
  id: string="";
  baño: number=0;
  estacionamiento: number=0;
  metro: number=0;
  precio: number=0;
  fotos: string[]=[];

}
```

esa clase la importo en la COMPONENTE1 donde la lleno de datos a traves de una peticion a una API. Lo que quiero es (luego de llenar ese objeto) pasarlo a la COMPONENTE2, lo que esta pensando era hacer esto en COMPONENTE2:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Inmueble } from '../modelos/inmueble';

class {
  @Input() vector: inmueble[];
}
```

Aquì estan los codigos del componente hijo:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { Inmueble } from '../modelos/inmueble';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() prueba: Inmueble;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
   console.log("=============="+this.prueba.nombre);
  }

  

}
```

```html
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <div class="alert alert-primary text-center" style="width: 100%;" role="alert"> <h1> HOLA {{prueba.nombre}} </h1></div>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex flex-row">

    <div class="d-inline-flex" style="width: 100px; height:100px;"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="">   </div>
    <div class="d-inline-flex ml-2" style="width: 100px; height:100px;"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="">   </div>
    <div class="d-inline-flex ml-2" style="width: 100px; height:100px;"> <img src="../assets/images/slider/4.jpg" alt="">   </div>
    </div>

    <div class="" id="cont-descripcion">
      <p class="text-center">Descripcion</p>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-borderless">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <thead>
              <tr>
                <th><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Ubicacion: </th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td class="text-center"> <i class="fas fa-bath fa-2x "></i> <p> Baños: 1 <p> </td>
          <td class="text-center"> <i class="fas fa-hot-tub fa-2x"></i> <p> Baños de Servicio: 1 <p> </td>

          <td class="text-center"> <i class="fas fa-bed fa-2x"></i> <p> Habitaciones: 2 <p> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-center"> <i class="fas fa-ruler fa-2x "></i> <br/>metros construidos: 100</td>
          <td class="text-center"> <i class="fas fa-ruler fa-2x "></i> <br/>metros de terreno: 100</td>
          <td class="text-center"> <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chVerTutoriales" onclick="btTutorial.disabled = !this.checked"><br/>Pago Condominio</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Caractetisticas Adicionales</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

pero como hago para el objeto lleno desde COMPONENTE1 a la COMPONENTE2 ? en los ejemplos veo que lo hacen para una sola variable asì: [variable] = "valor", pero esto seria un vector y piendo que hacerlo linea por linea seria muy inifeciente. lo que quiero lograr con esto es mostrar ese objeto en la plantilla de COMPONENTE2. Gracias a todos de antemano. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Si tus componentes van a ser padre hijo la forma correcta como dices es utilizando el @Input. En este [enlace](https://victorroblesweb.es/2016/11/07/input-output-angular-2/) se explica de forma bastante sencilla.

Simplemnte en tu componente padre tendrás algo como:

```
<componente-hijo [valor]="myObj"></componente-hijo>
```

Y en el componente hijo lo recogerías así:

```
@Input() valor: any;
```

Con eso ya tendrías todos los datos del objeto en la variable "valor" del componente hijo. Y podrías acceder a ella vía `this.valor`

Si tienes un array y no quieres mandarlo entero simplemente cuando llames al hijo dices que objeto envias:

```
<componente-hijo [valor]="myArr[1]"></componente-hijo>
```

O bien envias todo el array y posteriormente en el hijo recuperas la posición:

```
<componente-hijo [valor]="myArr"></componente-hijo>

@Input() valor: any;
let obj = this.valor[1];
```

Comment: Eso justamente es lo que estoy tratando de hacer y no me funciona, no me muestra nada cuàndo desde el .html del componente hijo intento valor[i].nombre

Comment: pero tienes puesto @Input() valor: inmueble[];  Tienes creada alguna entidad inmueble a parte? Prueba a declarar ese valor como any. Y luego accede a la posición que quieres.

Comment: es @Input() variable: Inmueble; ahorita lo tengo asì. donde Inmueble es la clase que muestro en mi pregunta y la estoy importando en esa componente.

Comment: si imprimo desde el .ts asì: this.variable.nombre si lo imprime, pero cuàndo hago {{ prueba.nombre }} en el .html no me lo muestra, alguna idea por que sea eso?

Comment: Puedes subir el codigo HTML del hijo? TS y HTML? a ver que está pasando?

Comment: hola @Findelias , ya edite mi pregunta.

Comment: No veo ningún {{prueba.baños}} pro ej en el HTML. Se te ha olvidado?. Que es lo que pinta el console.log del ts?

Comment: Solamente estoy mandando a mostrar prueba.nombre en el html.

Comment: Y que te pinta el console log?

Comment: En consola me esta mostrando los valores que deben estar en this.prueba.nombre .

Comment: ==============Vendo casa parque lefevre , ==============Apartamento en venta en Downtown Panama 55, Obarrio , ==============En venta hermoso apartamento nuevo en PH Venezia, El Carmen , esos es lo que me muestra, que son los valores que deberìa mostrar en el .html

Answer (score 0):

probado y funcionando:

En el component que envia

```
 capturaMovimientos(rowSelect) {
 const dato: NavigationExtras = {state: {example: rowSelect}};
      this.router.navigate(['/movimientos-sua'], dato);
    }
```

En el ngOnInit del component que recibe

```
const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
  let objeto= navigation.extras.state as {example: Trabajadores};
  this.trabajador = objeto.example as Trabajadores;
  console.info(this.trabajador.nombre);
```